# Array upgrading

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

If I understand [Section 15.1.2.1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/15_aba.htm) of the Common Lisp standard correctly, it is perfectly legal for `(upgraded-array-element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))` to be `'(unsigned-byte 16)`, or even `t`.  My question is therefore about the actual behavior of implementations.

Are there any implementations in use today where `'(unsigned-byte 8)` or `'(unsigned-byte 16)` are upgraded?  In other words, where the following is false:

```
(and (subtypep (upgraded-array-element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)) '(unsigned-byte 8))
     (subtypep (upgraded-array-element-type '(unsigned-byte 16)) '(unsigned-byte 16))
```

(The expression is true for SBCL, CLISP, Allegro CL, Clozure CL, and LispWorks.)

Answer (score 1):

ECL may not support `'(unsigned-byte 16)`